# Partitioning Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I am a Windows user. Currently I am switching to Ubuntu 18.04. My hard disk size is 1TB. When I am going to create partitions during Ubuntu installation I want to create 4 partitions like Windows does, such as:

<sub>Local disk(C) - size 200 GB

 Local disk(D) - size 200 GB

 local disk(E) - size 250 GB

 local disk(F) - size 300 GB</sub>

How can I create these 4 partitions?

Comment: During installation you are asked if you want to (1) wipe the disk completely (2) install Ubuntu in an existing partition or (3) do something else. Choose Something else. You will be taken to a `gparted` screen where you can create these partitions the way you want.

Comment: Ubuntu is a \*nix (unix like OS) and doesn't have drive letters like cp/m or msdos(windoze).  All files/drives are 'mounted' somewhere in your filesystem (/ being the top).  User files generally go in '/home[/username]' and splitting files into drive-letters makes no sense.  / is usually for system files; you make a partition for your /home (so upgrades or re-installs that require re-formatting won't effect your data), other partitions are up to you. If you leave space for d/e/f - where will you mount those (as you won't have drive-letters or old CP/M legacy from floppy days division)

Comment: Could you explain what are you going to use all those partitions for? This could help in defining the mount points you should use for them and make clear whether they are really needed.

Comment: I want to use one partition for all ubuntu systems objectives,And others ar for my personal data

Comment: So there are still 3 partitions for the same purpose? This is still not well-explained…

Answer (score 3):

User @Jos gave already a good answer in his comment.

Just to clarify it further: it's true that Ubuntu has somewhat different partitioning model than Windows and thus doesn't use letters for partitions.
But you can freely place additional partitions (mount it) under `/media/` directory - but of course, please reserve at least one partition for the Ubuntu needs (or alternatively two):

1. one for Ubuntu itself under `/` - equivalent of `C:` in Win (20 or 30 GB would be enough)
2. and the second for users directories `/home` - equivalent of `D:` (let's say 200 GB).

All remaining partitions you can place under `/media/` directory. Sth like:

1. `/media/e`
2. `/media/f`
3. `/media/g`

You can do it during the installation by choosing `Something else`, or even later, after the installation, with the mentioned `GParted` program.

Comment: 15 GB for / is minimum, I would suggest 20 or 30 GB to avoid problems with full root file system some time in the future.

Comment: @SorenA sure, I've edited my answer.

Comment: I am facing a problem with mount options.  What I should selected, primary or logical, and then / or / home,  /boot, /usr etc I cant decide what should I select

Comment: @HimelAhmed  Create e.g. one primary for `/` and all others logical. But probably whatever you do, it will work.

Comment: logical and /home or /boot  or /usr Which I use?

Comment: @Melebius it's a misunderstanding :). I've advised to have one single root partition instead of three separate. Since 5 mins passed and I cannot edit my comment. I'll delete it and post a new one.

Comment: All others partitions can be logical. And please save yourself time and just create a one, single partition for all: `/`, `/boot` and `/usr`. I do this way my whole life and I'm happy. Ps. take a look here for details: [How to use manual partitioning during installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation).